# WSO2 Identity Server - Customize SAMLSSOAuthenticator

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to write a custom federated authenticator. The reason for this is that I want to retrieve claims from multiple data sources and include them as attributes in the SAML Response to my application.
I looked at a custom claim handler :

http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.ie/2014/07/adding-custom-claims-to-saml-response.html

Unfortunately, when logging in directly to external IDP, the custom claim handler shall not be invoked.

To create a custom SAMLSSOAuthenticator, I created a custom class:

```
public class CustomSAMLSSOAuthenticator extends SAMLSSOAuthenticator implements FederatedApplicationAuthenticator {
    @Override
    protected void processAuthenticationResponse(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
                                                 final AuthenticationContext context) throws AuthenticationFailedException {
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CustomSAMLSSOAuthenticator";
    }

    @Override
    public String getFriendlyName() {
        return "custom-samlsso";
    }                                                
}
```

Then I registered the class in OSGi as an AbstractApplicationAuthenticator. I can see this registration in the logs working:

```
DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.internal.FrameworkServiceComponent} -  Added application authenticator : CustomSAMLSSOAuthenticator
```

Then I make changes to $IS_HOME/repository/conf/security/application-authentication.xml:

```
<AuthenticatorNameMapping name="CustomSAMLSSOAuthenticator" alias="firecrest-samlsso" />
...
<AuthenticatorConfig name="CustomSAMLSSOAuthenticator" enabled="true">
```

and I removed reference to SAMLSSOAuthenticator from file.

From Mgmt console, when adding Advanced Authentication configuration for my service provider, and selecting federated authenticators, I was expecting to see option custom-samlsso, but I only get samlsso, and when logging into external IDP, this is still getting handled with SAMLSSOAuthenticator and not CustomSAMLSSOAuthenticator.

I also notice in the IdPManagementUIUtil class, that there is some hardcoding of SAMLSSOAuthenticator which may indicate that what I am attempting to do is unsupported:

```
private static void buildSAMLAuthenticationConfiguration(IdentityProvider fedIdp,
        Map<String, String> paramMap) throws IdentityApplicationManagementException {

    FederatedAuthenticatorConfig saml2SSOAuthnConfig = new FederatedAuthenticatorConfig();
    saml2SSOAuthnConfig.setName("SAMLSSOAuthenticator");
    saml2SSOAuthnConfig.setDisplayName("samlsso");
    ...
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach of replacing the existing SAMLSSOAuthenticator is problematic as there are certain hard-codings associated with it as outlined in question.

The solution is just to add a new custom authenticator and make it look as close as possible to SAMLSSOAuthenticator:

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Writing+a+Custom+Twitter+Authenticator

The only problem I have is getting the configuration form on the management console to look the same:

```
@Override
public List<Property> getConfigurationProperties() {
    final List<Property> properties = Lists.newArrayList();
    properties.add(createProperty(IdentityApplicationConstants.Authenticator.SAML2SSO.IDP_ENTITY_ID, null,
        "Identity Provider Entity Id", "Enter identity provider's entity identifier value", true, null, null));

    ...    
    return properties;
}    

private Property createProperty(final String name, final String value, final String label,
                                final String description, final boolean required, final String type,
                                final String defaultValue) {
    final Property property = new Property();
    property.setName(name);
    property.setValue(value);
    property.setDisplayName(label);
    property.setDescription(description);
    property.setRequired(required);
    if (type != null) {
        property.setType(type);
    }
    property.setDefaultValue(defaultValue);
    return property;
}
```

I'm not sure what are valid values for the Property#type?
Couldn't determine if there is a way to create check-boxes and radio buttons using the Property type?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is supported to add custom authenticators as preferred and hard coded values are only applicable to default packed authenticator. Even though the configuration is not visible it seems it is in effective which you would be able to validate by trying out to authenticate via it. The configurations of custom authenticator are shown only when the configuration properties are defined within the custom implementation. So please try adding some properties via this method which is present in Abstract class.

```
public List<Property> getConfigurationProperties()
```

On the other hand, your first approach should have worked. If you can send over the code would be able to check what has gone wrong.